# Convert Python2.6 to Google App Engine compatible (multiprocessing)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, multiprocessing

I've made a little script in Python which uses multiprocessing. I've thought of running it on the Google App Engine as a cron-job, but unfortunately Google App Engine doesn't support multiprocessing. Can anyone help me convert this into Google App Engine compatible code (perhaps using Google App Engine tasks?)?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import MySQLdb
import urllib;
import urllib2;

def f(email_url):
    url = "http://my-domain.com/cron.php"
    values = { "email" : email_url[0], "url" : email_url[1] }
    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
    urllib2.urlopen(req)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool()
    emails_urls = list()
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", user = "USERNAME",
                           passwd = "PASSWORD", db = "MY-DATABASE")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute ("SELECT email, url FROM data")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        emails_urls.append((row[0], row[1]))
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    p.map(f, emails_urls)
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at Task Queues.

ca can insert an amount of work into a task Queue (=> Thread) and set the number of jobs in a queue which are executed simultaniously.

Take a look here: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/

Comment: The deferred library, which is a wrapper around task queues, would be an even better fit for the current functionality of this script.  http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html